# Why is my container size not relative to text size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

```
<section id="slide-2" class="homeSlide">
    <div class="bcg"
        data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;"
        data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;"
        data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% 100px;"
        data-anchor-target="#slide-2"
    >
        <div class="hsContainer">
            <div class="hsContent"
                data-center="opacity: 1"
                data-center-top="opacity: 0"
                data--100-bottom="opacity: 0;"
                data-anchor-target="#slide-2"
            >
            <h2>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText
                TextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</h2>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </section>
```

Why is my `container size not relative` to text size? Why is it taking the full width? How can i reduce the width of container which `carries the h2 text`?

http://jsfiddle.net/bMCb8/

Answer (score 1):

Both `div` and `h2` are block elements. That means that unless you specify a width they will take up the available width. To achieve what you want you might try to set `display: inline;` on the `h2`-element. This however will not work when the element has `position: fixed` in that case you need to set position fixed on a wrapping element.

http://jsfiddle.net/bMCb8/1/

[Se more about position fixed display inline issue](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)